# Ineligible for paid holiday

Tags: salaried-pay, holidays, exempt

I'am a salaried exempt employee and I gave my 2 weeks notice with a November 24th as a last day. Some plans came up so I requested the 24th off work. My HR manager sent me an email stating that I may be ineligible for paid holiday which is the 23rd since my last working day is the 22nd. Is this possible? because I am technically employed until the 24th.

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: If your HR manager says no, it sounds like the answer is no.  They should be more familiar with company policy than any of us.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a contract that says otherwise companies are not required to pay for holidays.

Many companies have a policy that in order to be eligible you must work the day before and after the holiday that you are scheduled in order to qualify for holiday pay.

The intent of this is to prevent people from calling in sick right before or after holidays when often there is a busy schedule. But it also works in cases where someone gives notice during holiday times. The company is not benefited by paying you for time after you have stopped working for them.

Answer (score 2):

The last day you are in the office is Wednesday November 22nd the day before a paid holiday. That is the time they will collect your badge, office key, parking pass, laptop, credit card; and have you submit the final time card. Thus ending your employment.

They don't want to try and get these things from you after your last day in the office. They don't want you to still have a key after you are no longer employed.

If they are the source of your health insurance plan, that last day in the office may also be the last day you can use the health insurance. Though some do have policies that cover you to the end of the pay period or to the end of the month.

The good news is that many places must pay for unused vacation, and even those that aren't legally forced to pay it, do so anyway. So if they give you credit for unused vacation you will be paid for Friday.

My advice to employees calculating their last day of work: Understand that what the company can do, may not match what you want them to do. If asked my advice before giving notice, I would have expected the company to insist on the last day being the day before the holiday, just to make sure they don't have to figure out who will be there to perform the out-process on the Friday after Thanksgiving.